# ZB IDE search and replace extension types

Tags: search, zerobrane

I have two types of lua:  5.1 .lua extension and 5.1 Family Historian lua 
 .fh_lua extension, I have several non-executable as stand alone files that have the extension .lua, all of my working code is extenison .fh_lua, mostly works well, and the .lua files do not appear as FH plugins, which I desire.  However when searching (or search replacing) though both files are in my same directory and project for zb, it does not search the .lua files only .fh_lua I would like to search both.

this is my sys pref file, I have an empty user pref, making my  zb ide global for all users.

```
autoanalyzer          = true
console.fontname      = 'Courier New'
console.fontsize      = 10
default.extension     = 'lua'
filetree.showchanges  = true 
editor.autoreload     = true
editor.fontname       = 'Courier New'
editor.fontsize       = 12 
editor.specmap.fh_lua = 'lua'
editor.specmap.wlua   = 'lua'
local luaspec         = ide.specs.lua
luaspec.exts[#luaspec.exts + 1] = 'fh_lua'
editor.tabwidth       = 2
editor.smartindent    = true
editor.indentguide    = wxstc.wxSTC_IV_LOOKBOTH        --prf 
editor.wrapindentmode = wxstc.wxSTC_WRAPINDENT_INDENT  --prf
acandtip.shorttip = false )
```

Answer (score 0):

> However when searching (or search replacing) though both files are in my same directory and project for zb, it does not search the .lua files only .fh_lua I would like to search both.

You can specify both of the extensions in the search path window: `<some path>; *.lua, *.fh_lua`. This should make the search in `<some path>` folder with two extensions.